# Elasticsearch Integration High Level and Low Level APIs

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have built Elasticsearch Query (DSL) as below. I want to integrate it from Java Application. When I read High and Low Level REST Options are given by Elastic. Is it possible to build complex queries using High Level API? OR I shall go with Low Level API and build the DSL through Program?

```
GET myindex/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "nested": {
              "path": "blog_types",
              "query": {
                "match": {
                  "blog_types.blog_type": 45649
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "nested": {
              "path": "blog_types",
              "query": {
                "match": {
                  "blog_types.blog_type": 45647
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "filter" : {
            "geo_bounding_box" : {
                "request_location.location" : {
                    "top_left" : {
                        "lat" : 50.925996,
                        "lon" : 4.584309
                    },
                    "bottom_right" : {
                        "lat" : 50.845996,
                        "lon" : 4.494309
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The High Level REST client allows you to build complex queries like the one above, look here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-query-builders.html

Comment: Any sample code for reference? All I could do is simple query, when it comes to multiple conditions Im kind of stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here goes:

```
QueryBuilder blogType1 = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("blog_types", 
    QueryBuilders.matchQuery("blog_types.blog_type", 45649), ScoreMode.Avg);

QueryBuilder blogType2 = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("blog_types", 
    QueryBuilders.matchQuery("blog_types.blog_type", 45647), ScoreMode.Avg); 

QueryBuilder geo = QueryBuilders.geoBoundingBoxQueryBuilder("request_location.location")
    .setCorners(50.925996, 4.584309, 50.845996, 4.494309);

QueryBuilder mainQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .filter(blogType1)
    .filter(blogType2)
    .filter(geo);
```

If you want OR conditions, you can do it like this using `should`:

```
QueryBuilder blogType1 = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("blog_types", 
    QueryBuilders.matchQuery("blog_types.blog_type", 45649), ScoreMode.Avg);

QueryBuilder blogType2 = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("blog_types", 
    QueryBuilders.matchQuery("blog_types.blog_type", 45647), ScoreMode.Avg); 

QueryBuilder geo = QueryBuilders.geoBoundingBoxQueryBuilder("request_location.location")
    .setCorners(50.925996, 4.584309, 50.845996, 4.494309);

QueryBuilder mainQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .should(blogType1)
    .should(blogType2)
    .filter(geo)
    .minimumShouldMatch(1);
```

Comment: How to mention the conditions between "blogType1" and "blogType2" incase I want to make it OR condition, how to mention the condition?

Comment: Thank you !! But what I want is like this ... ("blogType1" OR "blogType1") AND ("geo")

Comment: Ah OK. Just curios if I have another condition like  ((("blogType1" OR "blogType1") AND ("geo")) OR ("newCondition1" OR "newCondition2") ), How this will change?

Comment: You need to play with the bool query using `should` (OR) + `filter/must` (AND) and combine them to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

For future users : 
Suppose we want to use ES Client to replicate this query:

```
  {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "table_name": {
                    "query": "google",
                    "operator": "and"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "table_name": {
                    "query": "yahoo",
                    "operator": "and"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "vendor_type": {
                    "query": "9",
                    "operator": "and"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Use this code to get the follwing:

```
    //Sub Query of MustBool
    BoolQueryBuilder mustNotBoolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    mustNotBoolQueryBuilder.mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("vendor_type",  String.valueOf(DBVendor.Collibra.getValue())).operator(Operator.AND));

    //Sub Query of MustBool
    BoolQueryBuilder shouldBoolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    assetNames.forEach(assetName -> {
        shouldBoolQueryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("table_name",assetName).operator(Operator.AND));
    });

    //Root Bool
    BoolQueryBuilder mustBoolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    mustBoolQueryBuilder.must(shouldBoolQueryBuilder);
    mustBoolQueryBuilder.must(mustNotBoolQueryBuilder);
```